# Calling another function in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using AngularJs 1.5 RC build.
I have a view wherein I am using `ng-repeat` to iterate over a collection , like so

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users">
    <td>{{user.JobID}}</td>
    <td>{{getManager(user.userID)}}</td>
    <td>{{user.StatusDesc}}</td>
    <td>{{user.StartedAt}}</td>
</tr>
```

The idea here is to use the `getManager` function to get the name of the manager for each and every user in the users collection.
As an aside , I have to use this approach since the API is not returning me all the information.

This is how the `getManager` function looks like now.

```
 $scope.getManager = function($id) {
      return "John Doe";
  }
```

The entire controller looks as follows

```
var app = angular.module('userapp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('MainController', ['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.getUsers = function() {

    $http.get("http://localhost/getUsers").
       success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
         $scope.users = data.resource;
       }).
       error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
         // log error
         console.error("An error as encountered. Error follows:");
         console.error(data);
       });
  }

  $scope.getManager= function($id) {
      return "John Doe";
  }


}]);
```

So in my page view, I am getting "John Doe" as a manager for all my users.

**Problem**
The problem begins whenever I try to get the real manager for a user. So if i replace my dummy `getManager` with the following function

```
  $scope.getManager = function($id) {
      $http.get("http://localhost/user/manager/"+$id).
         success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            return (data.resource[0].ManagerName);

         }).
         error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
           // log error
           console.error("An error as encountered. Error follows:");
           console.error(data);
         });
  }
```

AngularJs starts complaining and fails with the following
https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D

Can you please let me know what might be happening here. 
Please note , I am *an Angular noob*, hence your patience will be well appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call ajax in that way inside `{{}}` interpolation. It will get called on each digest cycle and will throw `$rootScope/infdig` error.

So I'd suggest you to call the `getManager` method as soon as you retrieve a data from server. Then after getting data from a server you need to call `getManager` method just by passing `UserId`(look I change `getManager` implementation to return managerName by returning data). After getting managerName you need to bind that manager name to user object & use `{{user.ManagerName}}` on the HTML.

**Markup**

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users">
    <td>{{user.JobID}}</td>
    <td>{{user.managerName}}</td>
    <td>{{user.StatusDesc}}</td>
    <td>{{user.StartedAt}}</td>
</tr>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.getUsers = function() {
   $http.get("http://localhost/getUsers")
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.users = data.resource;
      angular.forEach($scope.users, function(user){
         (function(u){
             $scope.getManager(u.UserID).then(function(name){
                 u.ManagerName = data;
             })
         })(user);
     })
   })
 };


 $scope.getManager = function($id) {
      return $http.get("http://localhost/user/manager/"+$id).
         then(function(response) {
            var data = response.data;
            return (data.resource[0].ManagerName);
         },function(error) {
           console.error("An error as encountered. Error follows:");
         });
 };
```

> **Side Note**
>
> Don't use .success & .error function on $http calls as they are
>   deprecated.

Comment: Thanks.. Will give that a try and let you know how it goes. Please allow me some time.

Comment: ok . So this works.. I was getting an error, whenever I tried your code. However I think , I managed to get it working by replacing u.ManagerName = data with u.ManagerName = name.. Is that correct ?

Comment: Yes..i assumed that property you could change that

Comment: which I did.. thanks.. I have marked your answer as the correct one

Answer (score 0):

This is a really bad practice. If you have N users, you will send N queries to fetch every data. You should return this data in `http://localhost/getUsers` response.

You can try:

```
$scope.getManager = function($id) {
  return $http.get("http://localhost/user/manager/"+$id)
    ...
}
```

Comment: I agree this is bad practice , but, unfortunately. I have no control over that.  (as I already stated in the question). Though in all cases, N is a small number.